# Initializing Kinect Recorder error

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect.toolbox

When I attempt to run my skeletal tracking code to test out the following line of code I have added in, it crashes with an error.

```
    void sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (closing)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Get a skeleton
        Skeleton first = GetFirstSkeleton(e);

        if (first == null)
        {
            return;
        }


        using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
        {
            //if (skeletonFrame == null)
            //{
            //    return;
            //}
            this.recordStream = new MemoryStream(100);
            KinectRecorder Recorder = new KinectRecorder(KinectRecordOptions.Skeletons, recordStream);
            if (skeletonFrame != null)
            {
                this.Recorder.Record(skeletonFrame);
            }
            //StartRecord
           // Skeleton[] skeletonData = this.Recorder.Record(skeletonFrame);

        }
 // some more stuff
 }
```

I am calling the Record function available in the Kinect Toolbox.

The error is: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled .......  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 ..... Source=SkeletalTracking

Update:
If I have moved the initialization into the same function as the call of the recorder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've posted, you never initialize your `KinectRecorder`.

```
this.Recorder.Record(skeletonFrame); // I get an error after the RGB camera view freezes
```

... would produce a null pointer, because `Recorder` was never initialized.  Unless you've left that part out of your code example here.  You can do it at the time you declare it, or later if you prefer.

```
KienctRecorder Recorder = new KinectRecorder(options, stream);
```

`options` need to be set up for your appropriate `KinectRecordOptions`.  `stream` is your output `Stream`.

Comment: if I want the stream to record be the skeleton data, and I have a Stream recordStream variable declared, what would be the output Stream......................... KinectRecorder Recorder = new KinectRecorder(KinectRecordOptions.Skeletons, ???);............. i have updated with more info my question above.

Comment: The `Stream` is the file output stream - that is, where do you want to be saving the data.  It is set up like a normal file `Stream`.

Comment: The `stream` should generally be a file - for example: `File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create)`.  Try working with it, and see what happens.  The code for Kinect Toolbox is all open, so you can look at it and see exactly what each function is expecting.